# How android:configChanges="orientation" flag affects ACTIVITY STACK when it includes translucent activities?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, orientation, android-orientation

Have following Activities

- MainActivity
- TranslucentChildActivity
- DialogGrandChildActivity

**NOTE:** android:configChanges="orientation" is mentioned in Manifest for TranslucentChildActivity so that doesn't get re-created

1. MainParentActivity startActivityForResult  -->  TranslucentChildActivity
2. TranslucentChildActivity startActivityForResult  -->  DialogGrandChildActivity
3. Now change orientation

   - DialogGrandChildActivity  should be destroyed and re-created
   - TranslucentChildActivity should also be affected as it is in the background of the dialog activity but since onConfigChange flag is set it shouldn't be destroyed
4. BUT UNFORTUNATELY  TranslucentChildActivity is also destroyed and re-created and onConfigurationChanged() callback isnt called which is surprising...

**Questions:**

1. android:configChanges="orientation" flag isn't applicable to translucent activities?
2. How do I stop this translucent activity from being re-cycled?

I tried quite a few ways without any success. I would appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**My Observations:**

- Even though the translucent child activity has the flag set to handle its orientation change it will be ineffective if the MainParentActivity behind the translucent doesn't have the flag android:configChanges="orientation" set
- Since the main parent is killed the whole activity stack will be destroyed and re-created
- No matter if any child has any flag set
- It will all be overridden